# How to show only paragraph when cursor is on the heading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in web designing. How do I make a paragraph only visible when the cursor is on the M IRFAN HAIDER(heading). I made a heading containing a name "M Irfan Haider" and a paragraph with the content in between `<p>` tags.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="section "id="p1"" >
 <span class="name">M Irfan Haider</span>
 <span class="border"></span>
 <p>
        McDonald’s leadership draws from a proud history and set of values that made the company an icon of American business. Meet our President and CEO, as well as other McDonald’s executive team members who continue to build our legacy, and ensure our Golden Arches shine bright.
 </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `p {
  display:none;
}

.name:hover + span + p{
  display:block;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using just CSS. There is no need for JavaScript.

The best way to make this work in your exact example, is to add appropriate ID tags, and then when one of them is on hover, you can alter the display of another ID tagged element.

```css
#name:hover ~ #p-text-1 {
  display: block;
}

.p-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section" id="p1">
    <span class="name" id="name">M Irfan Haider</span>
    <span class="border"></span>
    <p class="p-text" id="p-text-1">
      McDonald’s leadership draws from a proud history and set of values that made the company an icon of American business. Meet our President and CEO, as well as other McDonald’s executive team members who continue to build our legacy, and ensure our Golden
      Arches shine bright.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```